# How do I brew beer?

Tags: fiz

I just started my own brewery but all the ingredients for the IPA and ale are grey ?s.  What ingredients do I need to brew them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To brew beer you need to open the menu (button in the top right of the screen) and then click brew. This brings up the brew screen;

[image]

From here you can:

- purchase new recipes from the "Recipes" tab,
- purchase individual ingredients or find out more about individual ingredients in the "Ingredients" tab, or
- start a brew by tapping the "Fill" button to automatically fill the ingredients table on the left of the screen before tapping on the "Next" bar on the right of the screen (where it currently says "Fill Recipe To Continue").

If you are still in the tutorial, you can only follow the on screen instructions (which will guide you through the creation of your first brew) until after you have put your first brew on sale.

Comment: I think I see the problem. It doesn't show me the ingredients until I buy the recipient.

Comment: stupid mobile spellcheck, I meant recipe :P

Comment: @spartacus That is by design - if you know the ingredients of a given recipe, you can actually save yourself the cost of purchasing the recipe. I believe there's a popup that tells you as much, actually.